# why my terminal shows this and not compile when I am using code Runner extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, compiler-errors, vscode-code-runner

I istalled code runner and worked for a while. Now its showing this error.
if i run my code normally(g++ demo.cpp) its working. I cant use that extension now. its showing

```
At line:1 char:32
+ cd "c:\Users\mhdsh\cpp files\" && g++ demo.cpp -o demo && "c:\Users\m ...
+                                ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
At line:1 char:56
+ cd "c:\Users\mhdsh\cpp files\" && g++ demo.cpp -o demo && "c:\Users\m ...
+                                                        ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
At line:1 char:59
+ ... pp files\" && g++ demo.cpp -o demo && "c:\Users\mhdsh\cpp files\"demo
+                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:1 char:86
+ ... pp files\" && g++ demo.cpp -o demo && "c:\Users\mhdsh\cpp files\"demo
+                                                                      ~~~~
Unexpected token 'demo' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
```

Comment: I don't know code runner, but could it be that code-runner does not know how to run shell script, respectively powershell, code?